# Select rows with distinct values for columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a SQL table containing 3 columns - LocationA, LocationB, LocationC

How do I return the rows for which there is a difference in the values?

For example,

```
LocationA, LocationB, LocationC
US, US, US ---------------> Row1
US, IN, US ---------------> Row2
IN, US, IN ---------------> Row3
```

I need to return Row2 and Row3 because these rows show 2 different values.

Comment: So `where LocationA <> LocationB OR LocationB <> LocationC`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to use ISNULL if the columns are nullable :

```
WHERE ISNULL(LocationA,'NULL') <> ISNULL(LocationB,'NULL') 
    OR ISNULL(LocationB,'NULL') <> ISNULL(LocationC,'NULL')
```

Comment: Use of `ISNULL` on a column on the `WHERE` isn't really recommended. Better `OR` logic would be better. In 2022+ you could even use `IS DISTINCT FROM`.